# Why are bat'leths "swords"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, weapon, klingon-language

**Bat'leths** are generally referred to as **swords**.

[Bat'leth](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bat'leth) translates as "sword of honor".   And, for example, Kahless's bat'leth is called the [Sword of Kahless](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kahless)

Yet [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sword) is a generic definition of *sword*:

> a weapon having various forms but consisting typically of a long, straight or slightly curved blade, sharp-edged on one or both sides, with one end pointed and the other fixed in a hilt or handle.

[image: Some Bat'leths][image: Swords]

So there's some artistic license at work.

What are the in- and out-of-universe explanations for describing bat'leths as "swords" even though they are so unswordlike?  How did the use of the term "sword" in this context come to be?

Comment: The Klingon definition of the word *sword* might just differ from the Earth one? **Bat'leth** is just a translation, as you said, so if the Klingon define a sword that way, maybe the universal translators (or Hoshi before they/she invented it) just translated the word literally, disregarding the Earth definition?

Comment: @BMWurm That doesn't make sense, since it can't possibly have a "literal" translation other than what it actually means. If the Klingons define a _Bat'leth_ that way, then clearly it doesn't actually mean _sword_. They've never used nor heard of the word _sword_ before contact with humans.

Comment: Your dictionary definition is flawed. A sword _always_ has 2 edges, never one. Swords with a single edge are long knives (the distinction being made because peasants were allowed to carry the latter but not the former).

Comment: @Damon Whose rule for whose peasants? There wasn't exactly the UN back then. Scimitars, [sabres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabre), [katanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katana) and any curved sword can have one edge. I'd hardly call them knives. You can argue it with the samurai while they're cutting you in half.

Comment: @BMWurm, all this aside,  I'm also asking about out of universe where you can't deny the term used is "sword"

Comment: Because we often translate not just direct word-to-word translations, but translating concepts too. The literal translation would be "suicidally useless metal banana of honour".

Answer (score 23):

## Bat'leths were modelled upon Chinese fighting crescents.

According to its designer, **Dan Curry**, the bat'leth...

> **"...was modelled after a Chinese fighting crescent. Now it's become one of the icons associated with the show [*TNG*]."**

([Source](http://trekmovie.com/2011/04/18/visual-effects-artist-dan-curry-talks-about-time-with-star-trek-designing-the-batleth/))

Here is his original sketch:

[image]

As a [fighting crescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deer_horn_knives) is actually a type of knife, it might be better to classify the bat'leth as a *large knife* than as a sword.

As the reason for calling the weapon a "sword" is addressed neither in-universe nor out-of-universe, all we can say is that it seems to be a liberty that is being taken with the terminology.

There is, however, a relevant remark in the *bat'leth* entry at the official Star Trek web site:

> The traditional "sword of honor" preferred by Klingon warriors adept at the martial arts. About a meter long and **shaped as a double-semicircle with four points (resembling a two-ended scimitar)**, the bat'leth is carried along the inside of the arm and wielded using two handholds on the outside edge of the weapon.

([Source](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/batleth))

This suggests that the sword-like quality of the bat'leth might come from its relationship to the scimitar.

**But all in all, "Sword of Kahless" sounds more epic than "Knife of Kahless".**

Comment: I bet the authors were thinking: "lets create something looking absolutely bad-ass and that is absolutely impractical at the same time".

Comment: @Yasskier, it might actually make sense if you're strong and your opponent is armored.   And no one has ranged weapons.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Or considers using ranged weapons to be dishonorable in some situations, and thus avoided.

Comment: To be fair, a large knife is pretty similar in form to a sword.

Comment: @DavidZ In fact, saying "a large knife intended for combat" as the definition of "sword" is a pretty good one.  If this was based off a smaller crescent knife weapon, and is larger, and intended for combat, it would then fall under the word "sword".

Comment: @ThePopMachine not really: if you use it in both hands, you can only make sort of push which is very inefficient use of your muscles comparing to i.e. one handed punch and its too short and heavy to use fast attack from the ends like with quarterstaff. Using it in one hand makes bit more sense, but again punching with the middle part is inefficient (blade is curved inwards which will increase connecting surface reducing the impacting force - sabre is curved outwards) and lack of designed "safe" grip makes it swinging it like a sickle risky.

Comment: @Yasskier I am not sure, with minor tweaks it could be effective in half-swording. In fact, you can safely grab a sharp sword by the blade and use the crossguard to hit your opponent, it is called the murderer stroke. My only criticism is that it looks too heavy, and thus, slow compared to a sword.

Comment: The artistic license taken was the idea that a two handed [crescent moon knife](https://www.google.com/search?q=crescent+moon+knives&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYtLON2abMAhVIOCYKHeXoAN0Q_AUICCgC&biw=1024&bih=639) would make sense as a weapon. (you should include one of those pictures)

Comment: Saying that this does not fit the definition of sword is like digging up an old dictionary that defines "weight [n] the force attracting a body to the Earth" and then asking how we should call the force that attracted Armstrong et al. to the Moon.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:   This is a good point which I don't think anyone really made succinctly.   It speak to what the idea of *sword* represents rather than a definition based on what all previous "swords" had in common.

Answer (score 11):

The [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bat'leth#Design) section on the design out-of-universe is very detailed about it and has some interesting things to say.

- It's partially Dorn's fault: the article explains that Dorn wanted a weapon that had connotations of martial arts rather than barbarians, so there was a bit of a push for a samurai-inspired design.  One of the distinctive things about the samurai sword is that **it is [slightly curved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMZYo.jpg)** (*Star Trek: Communicator* issue 114, p. 59)
- It's also partially because they wanted something unique:

  > You know, there was this desire to have a particular, cool Klingon sword for Worf to use, that would become his, sort of, signature weapon,

  So this desire for some sort of 'sword' which was quite distinct is also part of the reason out-of-universe.  My guess would be that the term 'sword' was ingrained in the producers' minds and so they kept with that term, even though the Bat'leth technically wasn't a sword.
- The sources of inspiration, [Dan Curry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dan_Curry) tells us included (emphasis mine):

  > I'd been imagining a curved weapon partially influenced by **Himalayan weapons** like **the kukri** [the wickedly curved knife of the Gurkhas of Nepal, arguably the most renowned fighting knife in the world]. I was also thinking about the **Chinese double ax**, **Chinese fighting crescents**, and the **Tai Chi sword**. I combined elements of all those things in order to come up with an ergonomically sound weapon." (Star Trek: The Next Generation 365, p. 178) It was also important to Curry that the bat'leth *could be held with either two hands or one hand*. "He wanted a weapon that you could hold, you know, in a variety of ways," offered Ron Moore, "and have some interesting angles, on camera." ("Reunion" audio commentary, TNG Season 4 Blu-ray)

Now, for probably the most important part as to why this was called a sword (in my opinion at least) is the following quote:

> The final draft of the "Reunion" script describes the weapon by saying, "It is [a] semi-circular curved blade that branches to four points. It is about three feet wide. There is a terrible beauty about the blade [....] The bat'telh is held by two handles on the mid-exterior of the blade [....] *The bat'telh can be used as either **shield or sword***." (Memory Alpha sources [this](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/181.txt))

But, these are all out-of-universe accounts; as for the in-universe reason, we all know the tale of how Khaless forged his 'sword' which became known as the Bat'leth.  I'm inclined to agree with @Praxis that the in-universe reason is that 'The Sword of Khaless' sounds far more warrior like than 'The Blade of Khaless'!

Answer (score 7):

That's the generic definition of sword from an Earth dictionary.

The Klingon dictionary defines it differently, and is of course superior.

> [image]
>   A large blade, more than an arm length long, with a hand grip along the back or on one end.

Comment: Have you got a reference for this definition?

Comment: Presumably, this is the definition of a Klingon word.  Why is this specific Klingon word equated with "sword" in English?

Answer (score 5):

Because that's what we do with new, unfamiliar concepts that are reasonably similar to something much more familiar.  The Spanish explorers in the New World called llamas and alpacas "goats".  The English colonists in North America called bison "buffalo".  The human explorers who first encountered Klingon warriors and saw them using long-bladed martial weapons in close combat called them "swords."

Comment: This seems very opinion-based, not least because in-universe the translator is involved.

Comment: @Richard Maybe I missed something. Why do you find it inaccurate to talk about the way humans translate new concepts when dealing with a machine that is programmed to translate new concepts for humans?

Comment: I downvoted because you've made no attempt to explain why you think that your answer is right. You've just said "I'm right because I'm right". [Good answers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106114/20774) show references.

Answer (score 2):

It's a two handed weapon with a long curved blade you slash and thrust with. What else would you call it?

I think the translators went through a [list of premodern combat weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_premodern_combat_weapons), couldn't find anything that matched, and decided "sword" was the closest thing and easiest to understand.

"Sickle" sort of comes close, but they're intended to cut inward toward the body.

Comment: This is essentially the same as @MasonWheeler's answer.   You've expressed an opinion.  This is merely a reasonable conjecture without evidence.   Plus it doesn't answer the out of universe aspect.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I didn't see anyone else make this point (MasonWheeler answered after me). The out of universe answers have already been well-handled, no sense repeating them. Yes, it's a reasonable in-universe conjecture you may not have thought of; if you're only looking for answers supported by canon be sure to say so.

Comment: @Schwern:   I didn't mean to imply anything about the order of answering, just that the comments that apply there apply here too.